# SQL query returns nothing after minute 

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to filter my data using dates in the `WHERE` clause to get a good idea of when stuff happened. However, when I run the query I get no results and the query takes about a minute to fully complete. Any help is always greatly appreciated.

```
Declare @date datetime

set @date = getdate() - 11

Select ColumnA,ColumnB
From TableA
Where DateCreated >= @date And DateCreated < GetDate()
```

Comment: You could put index on DateCreated

Comment: do you really need `And DateCreated < GetDate()` ?

Answer (score 5):

**You don't have any records in your table that fall into that date range.**

or...

**`DateCreated` isn't a `datetime` field.**

It takes a minute likely because you don't have an index on that field and SQL is running a table scan to check every record.

Comment: Table was out of sync on the text server, got it now. Thanks

Comment: Although the impact might be minimal; stuffing GETDATE() into its own variable could help out as well

Comment: @Jim - good point, but likely pales in comparison to adding an index.  I think it will only calculate `GETDATE()` once per execution